# Is this class thread-safe?

Tags: apex, soql, force.com

I'm trying to prevent race conditions while adding sequential legs to these transactionIDs.  Does this look like a thread-safe implementation?

```
// only interact with TransactionCount__c using methods in this class
// Transactions start like 123.0 and may have multiple subsequent 
// legs 123.1, 123.2, 123.3...
// Transaction__c is an autonumber field.
// Leg__c contains the highest previously issued Leg value for that Transaction.
// isOpen defaults to TRUE.  Transactions are eligible for deletion when closed.

public static string nextTransaction() {
    TransactionCount__c tc = new TransactionCount__c();
    insert tc;

    // after insert only the ID is populated but other default values are not - why?

    // SELECT the TransactionCount__c to get the autonumber 
    // Transaction__c and default Leg__c values.
    // Locking here w/"for update" to prevent race conditions where other
    // threads close the transaction before this method has returned - unnecessary?
    tc =[SELECT Transaction__c, Leg__c FROM TransactionCount__c
    where id =:tc.id for update];
    return tc.Transaction__c + '.' + tc.Leg__c;
}

public static String getTransactionNoLeg(String transactionWithLeg) {
    // given "123.456"  returns "123"
    Integer i = transactionWithLeg.indexOf('.');
    if (i == -1) return transactionWithLeg;
    else return transactionWithLeg.substring(0, i);
}

public static String getLeg(String transactionWithLeg) {
    // given "123.456"  returns "456"
    // given "123" returns null
    Integer i = transactionWithLeg.indexOf('.');
    if (i == -1) return null;
    return transactionWithLeg.substring(i + 1);
}

public static boolean closeTransaction(String transactionWithOrWithoutLeg) {
    // returns TRUE if transaction was open
    // returns FALSE if transaction was already closed
    String trans = getTransactionNoLeg(transactionWithOrWithoutLeg);
    List<TransactionCount__c> tc =[SELECT isOpen__c FROM TransactionCount__c
    where transaction__c =:trans limit 1 for update];
    if (tc.size() == 0) throw new TransactionNotFoundException();
    if (tc[0].isOpen__c == false) return false;
    tc[0].isOpen__c = false;
    update tc;
    return true;
}

public static string nextTransactionLeg(String transactionWithOrWithoutLeg) {
    String trans = getTransactionNoLeg(transactionWithOrWithoutLeg);
    // transactionId.TransactionLeg
    List<TransactionCount__c> tc =[SELECT Transaction__c, Leg__c FROM TransactionCount__c
    where transaction__c =:trans limit 1 for update];
    if (tc.size() == 0) throw new TransactionNotFoundException();
    tc[0].Leg__c++;
    update tc;
    return tc[0].Transaction__C + '.' + tc[0].Leg__c;
}

public static void purgeClosedTransactions() {
    delete[select id from TransactionCount__c where isOpen__c =:false for update];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that you're doing anything async, so you shouldn't have concurrency problems in your SOQL calls.

To note, all you have are static methods.  Where are these methods being used?  Any concurrency problems you might run into will be solely based on **how** these static methods are being used.

Comment: The idea is these static methods can all be getting called by multiple users simultaneously.  I need to make sure that when two users call nextTransactionLeg() or nextTransaction() simultaneously they're not getting duplicate values so I'm using "for update" to (hopefully!) accomplish that.

Comment: Have you read Dan Appleman's book "Advanced Apex Programming" given out (for free) at Dreamforce?  You'll find a rich discussion there of exactly this topic.  FOR UPDATE is about the best you can do.  Sage Advice: try write test code to simulate this and see what happens =)

Comment: Haven't read it but I just ordered it.  thx